# Create html div with Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create html code like this in js

This is html code how i want to get with javascript

```
   <div id="windwo">
      <div id="windowhead">
      </div>
  </div>
```

And this is Javascript code test

```
   var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id = 'window';
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id = 'windowhead';
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        document.body.appendChild(div);
```

And out put of javascript code is

```
<div id="windowhead"></div>
```

Someone can tell me which i mistake done ?

Answer (score 2):

You need two DIV variables and to append the second DIV to the first:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'window';

var div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.id = 'windowhead';
div.appendChild(div2);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

You were essentially overwriting the first DIV with the second DIV.

Comment: output is  like  this <div id="windwo"></div>
      <div id="windowhead"> </div>

Answer (score 1):

```
var $widow = $('<div>', { id: "widow" });
$widow.append( $('<div>', { id: "widowhead"}) );
$('body').append( $widow );
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the same element twice. so just Change your JS as follows

```
    var div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.id = 'window';
    var div2 = document.createElement('div');
    div2.id = 'windowhead';
    document.body.appendChild(div1);
    div1.appendChild(div2);
```

Comment: I didn't down vote, but there is an additional issue with the `append` lines.

Comment: yes its working both but i didnt  understand      document.body.appendChild(div1);
    div1.appendChild(div2); this
first is document.body...;and  why  second is  div1.ap...; i am new in js if i get some explantion hmmm
jai bhart

Comment: it means that first, you have to add div1 to the body, then add div2 to div1, since you want div2 to be inside div1..